# Angular Universal: navigator is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular-universal, ngx-leaflet

I followed official angular-cli [tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering) to integrate angular-universal to my existing angular-cli app.

I am able to do SSR for my angular-cli app. But when I try to integrate [ngx-leaflet](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet), I am getting following error:

> ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
>       at D:\ng2-ssr-pwa\dist\server.js:40251:29

Now, I understand that leaflet is trying to access navigator object which is not available in the Node context. So I decided to delay leaflet rendering until the page is loaded in the browser as given in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800987/angular-2-and-implementing-leaflet-maps-open-street-map?rq=1#answer-43801401).
But still I am getting same error. You can look the demo app with leaflet issue [here](https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/ng2-universal-pwa).

**./src/app/browserModuleLoader.service.ts:**

```
import { Component, Inject, Injectable, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class BrowserModuleLoaderService {
    private _L: any;

    public constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private _platformId: Object) {
        this._init();
    }

    public getL() {
        return this._safeGet(() => this._L);
    }

    private _init() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this._platformId)) {
            this._requireLegacyResources();
        }
    }

    private _requireLegacyResources() {
        this._L = require('leaflet');
    }

    private _safeGet(getCallcack: () => any) {
        if (isPlatformServer(this._platformId)) {
            throw new Error('invalid access to legacy component on server');
        }

        return getCallcack();
    }
}
```

**./src/app/leaflet/app/leaflet.component.ts:**

```
// import * as L from 'leaflet';

import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModuleLoaderService } from '../browserModuleLoader.service';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-leaflet',
    styleUrls: ['./leaflet.component.scss'],
    template: `
      <div  *ngIf="isBrowser">
        <div leaflet [leafletOptions]="options"></div>
        </div>
  `,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class LeafletComponent {
    isBrowser: boolean;
    options = {};

    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: Object,
        private browserModuleLoaderService: BrowserModuleLoaderService
    ) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('this.isBrowser ', this.isBrowser);
        if (this.isBrowser) {
            const L = this.browserModuleLoaderService.getL();
            this.options = {
                layers: [
                    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 18, attribution: '...' }),
                ],
                zoom: 5,
                center: L.latLng({ lat: 38.991709, lng: -76.886109 }),
            };
        }
        this.cdr.detach();
    }

}
```

**./src/app/app.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <app-leaflet></app-leaflet>
</div>
```

How do I safely delay the leaflet rendering until the platform is not browser?

**EDIT:**

I removed all code related to leaflet (browserModuleLoader.service.ts, leaflet.component.ts ect. ) and kept only leaflet module import in app.module.ts and actually this import is causing issue.

**./src/app/app.module.ts:**

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import { BrowserModuleLoaderService } from './browserModuleLoader.service';
// import { LeafletComponent } from './leaflet/leaflet.component';
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // LeafletComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'my-app'}),
    LeafletModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    // BrowserModuleLoaderService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**./src/app/app.server.module.ts:**

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';
import {ModuleMapLoaderModule} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ServerModule} from '@angular/platform-server';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

How do I handle this nxg-leaflet module import?

Comment: Not sure if it'd work, but try `<div *ngIf="isBrowser"  leaflet [leafletOptions]="options"></div>`

Comment: still the same issue.

Comment: Is it the only place where you are using it? The other solution would be not importing  ngx-leaflet modulein your module.server.ts file

Comment: I am not importing ngx-leaflet in app.server.module.ts and importing it only in app.module.ts.

Comment: And in your app.server.module you are not importing 'app.module' ? If not, then it means that ngx-lealeft might not be the culprit. You should look at the server.js to try to see where it's coming from exactly

Comment: I am importing app.module in app.server.module, also I am sure culprit is ngx-leaflet only by looking at transpiled server.js (non prod build) and also if I remove all the code related to leaflet SSR works fine.

Comment: If possible can you pull the code from here and try to run: https://github.com/SaurabhLpRocks/ng2-universal-pwa

Comment: instead of importing app.module in app.server.module, you could try redeclaring all the same imported modules/providers, apart  from ngx-leaflet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved this issue by using [Mock Browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser).

**server.ts:**

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();


global['navigator'] = mock.getNavigator();
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was receiving this error with Angular Universal.  Using the Mock Browser from the solution above did fix this error for me, but it also started a new Warning related to CommonJS.  Rather than digging into that issue, I realized I was already using Domino in my server.ts file, so I could easily set the navigator with Domino.  This is what worked best for me:

`npm install domino`

*server.ts:*

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join('dist/<your-app-name>/browser', 'index.html')) //<--- REPLACE WITH YOUR APP NAME
  .toString();
const window = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;
global['navigator'] = window.navigator;
```

Answer (score 0):

@2024 Angular 17

I received the warning that Mock Browser uses deprecated components and after some research I discovered that Navigator is a window object and so if you intend to use the browser you can add a server check, take a look:

```
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // Use Navigator
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by `(global as any).navigator = win.navigator;`, much more elegant, definitely native, and without relying on outdated [Mock Browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-browser).

Comment: is the `win` in `win.navigator` is actually `window`? I'm running into this problem while running my angular ssr now.

Comment: @BelleZaid I don't remember all the details, other than it worked out :) More: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-770369651

Comment: thanks @Daniel. I did tried the comment in that issue before this, but still have the navigator not defined error still. I'm new with the angular universal things. So I can't find much on why this keep persisting.

Comment: @BelleZaid sorry to hear, but `Angular Universal` has really bad Developer Experience...

Comment: This is if you use domino, which requires you to import a huge package

Comment: Definitely not native, as "win" is not defined and it seems this needs another library

Comment: @Exitare, it was some time back, but the comment on GitHub seems to have more details: https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-770369651

Comment: `import { createWindow } from 'domino';...const win = createWindow(indexHtml);`